# Set selected value in a select

Tags: php, jquery, select, joomla

I have many selectboxes in my form. Everyone have the same option, But I don't know how set the value which should be selected.

This is my code:

```
function addSelect(id,id_status)
    {

        $('#sel_'+id)
        .find('option')
        .remove()
        .end();


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "",
            data:{
                option: 'com_zamowienia',
                view: 'zamowienia_lista',
                task: 'getStatusy'
            },
            success: function(data){

                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);         
                var tabela = [];
                for (x=0; x<obj.length; x++) {
                    tabela[x] =  
                        obj[x].nazwa;    

                }
                var zmienna =0;
                $.each(tabela, function(key, value) {
                    $('#sel_'+id)
                    .append($('<option>', { value : obj[zmienna].id_status})

                    .text(tabela[zmienna])
                    .css("color", "#"+obj[zmienna].kolor)

                ); 


                    zmienna++;
                });
               $('#sel_'+id).eq(id_status).attr('selected', 'selected')

            }
        });
```

I use this function like this:

```
for(x=0;x<obj.length; x++)
                    {
                        id = obj[x].id_produkt_lista;   
                        id_status =  obj[x].id_status;

                        $("#tab").find('tbody').append(
                        "<tr id='"+id+"'><td id ='' class =''>"+obj[x].nazwa_produkt+"</td>"
                            +"<td id=''>"
                            +"<select class = 'sel_' id='sel_"+id+"' id="+id+" ></select>"   
                            +"</td>" 
                            +"</tr> ");   


                               addSelect(id,id_status);
                            //$('#sel_'+id).eq(id_status).attr('selected', 'selected');
                    }
```

id -> id sleectbox id_status it's value which should be selected for select which have id = "#sel_"+id

Comment: `"<select class = 'sel_' id='sel_"+id+"' id="+id+" ></select>"` - you're setting the `id` twice. Remove the second one and your commented code should work

Comment: not work... Everyone select set selected value to first value.

Comment: Make sure your `id`-s are **unique** and correct on your page. Then use `$('#sel_' + id_status).attr('selected', true);`

Comment: id is unique. Its id from table mysql. change to true not change my problem.

Comment: what's your `id` and `id_status` output? the `eq` isn't suitable in your case anyways

Comment: id -> identification select witch should be selected on id_status optnion. Ex 45 -> 5 so sel_45 should be set selected on val(5).

Comment: can you update your question with the actual generated HTML?

Comment: http://wklej.org/id/830920/   -> this is my part of code... sorry but I can't add it in this topic because i haven't lvl to do it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BdZLt/ - look here

Comment: it's work! Thx men. You are King!

Answer (score 1):

if you know the "value" in this case you know it (id_status)
then the quickest way is to set value to given select box:

```
$('#sel_' + id).val(id_status);
```